# Reload UIWebView with UIButton when both are implemented programmatically (Swift)

Tags: iphone, xcode, swift, uiwebview, uibutton

I have a UIWebView that loads a embed SoundCloud track. I copied the code from the website, created a html file, and included it inside of the Xcode project. It loads perfectly fine; however, I want the user to be able to reload the WebView since the UIWebView is very small and it does not have any navigation buttons. It simply displays SoundCloud embed widget.

Is there a way to achieve this **without** using the **Interface Builder**? The app crashes when the button is tapped.

I have implemented the **UIWebView** and **UIButton** onto the screen **programmatically** because the size and coordinates of each will be different depending on the size of the iPhone screen.

The UIWebView is set to ***nil* before the viewDidLoad function** so it can be accessed in other functions (like the **reload** function).

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {

    let WebView: UIWebView! = nil
    override  func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let WebViewDetails = getCoordAndSize("WEBV") // stores 4 values into one variable. its a tuple
        let WebView = UIWebView(frame: CGRectMake(WebViewDetails.0, WebViewDetails.1, WebViewDetails.2, WebViewDetails.3))

        //load local html file
        let localfilePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("sctrack", withExtension: "html")
        let myRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: localfilePath!)
        WebView.loadRequest(myRequest)
        WebView.delegate = self

        let refreshButton = UIButton()
        refreshButton.setTitle("Refresh", forState: .Normal)
        refreshButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal)
        refreshButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        refreshButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        refreshButton.layer.borderWidth = 1
        refreshButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
        refreshButton.frame = CGRectMake((self.view.frame.size.width - 240) / 2, (imageViewDetails.2 - 40),240,40)


        //(LOOK HERE) BUTTON ACTION . What I want it to do is to reload html file when user taps on it
        refreshButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(reload), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(refreshButton)
    }
```

Below is the function for the **refreshButton**. When the user taps the button, it calls the reload function. I want it to reload the local file. I added the comment saying "ERROR HERE" to

```
    func reload(sender: UIButton!) {
        //ERROR HERE
        WebView.reload()

        let alertView = UIAlertController(title: "Message", message: "Track refreshed! Enjoy ✨", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        // Initialize Actions
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default) { (action) -> Void in
        }
        alertView.addAction(okAction)
        self.presentViewController(alertView, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

I've tried to include the html request inside of reload function and used **WebView.loadRequest(myRequest)** instead of **WebView.reload**, but the app still crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not initializing `WebView` which you have declared at class level. And again in `viewDidLoad` you are creating another variable with same name

```
      let WebView = UIWebView(frame: CGRectMake(WebViewDetails.0, WebViewDetails.1, WebViewDetails.2, WebViewDetails.3))
```

So your `WebView` used in `reload` method never initialized and hence the error/crash.

Remove `let` keyword in `viewDidLoad` for `WebView`. Everything will work fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Santosh!. I removed let from the class level and from viewDidLoad and it works! It's amazing how two words can crash an app.